# how to move captions below the whole slider using Anything slider

Tags: jquery, captions

I am using [anything slider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/).  I want to have the captions appear below the whole slider, perhaps in it's own div, separate from the slider. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?  I thought about trying to copy the caption with jQuery when it changes, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea?  Or is it even possible to do this?

Comment: What did you do so far? Can you please post some of your code?

Comment: Which slider are you using, there are many demos is Anything slider?